# Unable to use seaborn.countplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

I'm trying to plot some graphs using the latest version of Pycharm as a Python IDE.
As an interpreter, I'm using Anaconda with Python 3.4.3-0.
I have installed using `conda install` the news version of pandas (0.17.0), seaborn (0.6.0), numpy (1.10.1), matplotlib (1.4.3), ipython (4.0.1)

Inside the nesarc_pds.csv I have this:

```
IDNUM,S1Q2I
39191,1
39787,1
40082,1
40189,1
40226,1
40637,1
41306,1
41627,1
41710,1
42113,1
42120,1
42720,1
42909,1
43092,1
7,2
15,2
25,2
40,2
46,2
49,2
57,2
63,2
68,2
100,2
104,2
116,2
125,2
136,2
137,2
145,2
168,2
3787,9
6554,9
7616,9
11686,9
12431,9
14889,9
17694,9
19440,9
20141,9
21540,9
22476,9
24207,9
25762,9
29045,9
29731,9
```

So, that being said, this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import seaborn as snb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("nesarc_pds.csv", low_memory=False)

#converting variable to numeric
pd.to_numeric(data["S1Q2I"], errors='coerce')

#setting a new dataset...
sub1=data[(data["S1Q2I"]==1) & (data["S3BQ1A5"]==1)]
sub2 = sub1.copy()

#setting the missing data 9 = unknown into NaN
sub2["S1Q2I"] = sub2["S1Q2I"].replace(9, numpy.nan)

#setting date to categorical type
sub2["S1Q2I"] = sub2["S1Q2I"].astype('category')

#plotting

snb.countplot(x="S1Q2I", data=sub2)
plt.xlabel("blablabla")
plt.title("lalala")
```

And then.....this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/LPForGE_1/PycharmProjects/guido/haha.py", line 49, in <module>
        snb.countplot(x="S1Q2I", data=sub2)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 2544, in countplot
        errcolor)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 1263, in __init__
        self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 300, in establish_colors
        l = min(light_vals) * .6
    ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Any help would be really nice. I pretty much exhausted my intelligence trying to understand how to solve this.

Comment: Can you include a subset of data that reproduces the error?

Comment: if you don't include some data reproduces this error, there's not much anyone can do to help. it's your job as someone who needs help to make an example that we can copy and paste into a file and reproduce the behavior you want fixed.

Comment: Your example data doesn't work because you reference columns that don't exist.

Comment: removing the reference to the non-existent column, your code runs fine: https://gist.github.com/phobson/7ab50db5adb3e4427ea6