# Python - ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence when plotting graph from CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, lambda, seaborn

I have a CSV with the fields "Description" and "Area". I want to graph how many are in each area. I am getting the following error when I run my code:

```
----> 4 sns.countplot(x = feedback_df['Area'], order = varieties, ax = ax)
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Here is the code I am running to give a first pass at this :

```
feedback = pd.read_csv('feedback.csv')
feedback[feedback['Description'].duplicated(keep = False)].sort_values('Description').head(8)
feedback = feedback.drop_duplicates('Description')
feedback_df = feedback.groupby('Area').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 10599)
Types = feedback_df['Area'].value_counts().index.tolist()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (25, 10))
sns.countplot(x = variety_df['Area'], order = varieties, ax = ax)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Any chance this can be made reproducible for others? I.e. with a [mcve] and clear statement of versions in use.

Comment: You're probably referencing to a non-existent column. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151453/unable-to-use-seaborn-countplot Refer to this.